# Importing / referencing an external Silverlight dll library from a workflow 4.0 Activity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have created a Silverlight class library which holds a lot of the common utility methods I use day to day in my Silverlight development.

I am starting to play around with Workflow and would like to reuse this common dll. After referencing this dll in my workflow project I see a yellow warning icon beside it.

[image]

I can use the functionality from this dll when creating ‘Code Activities’ without issue. After adding the using statement for it all works AOK.

```
using EquinoxeAISManagementSystem.Common.Helpers;
```

**BUT** when I try to import the dll from the activity designer, I do not see the dll in the import window.

If I edit the XAML and add it directly, I get a warning.

[image]

Is it possible to reuse Silverlight dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I believe I can answer my own question.**
The project `EquinoxeAISMAnagementSsystem.Common` is part of another solution. I had added this single project for the other solution into my new workflow solution (which I was having this issue in).

When I added the reference to the `EquinoxeAISMAnagementSsystem.Common.dll` initilly, it was by referencing the project in the workflow solution.

[image]

This seems to be the cause of the issue (for workflow anyway).
I was able to correct this issue by adding the `EquinoxeAISMAnagementSsystem.Common.dll`  to a common folder where I keep all my external dlls (for ease of use).

```
..\Projects\EquinoxeAISManagementSystem.DLL\
```

I set up the output destination folder for this EquinoxeAISMAnagementSsystem.Common project to the folder above. I was then able to add the reference to `Common.dll` by browsing directly to the folder above.

Hay presto, **all works**.

I’m not sure id this is the *‘correct’* way to do things, but I needed to get over this hump. 
I would be interested in anyone’s comments and if there is a correct(er), why to fix this issue.

Thanks ….